# When shut down all nodes in one region of Apache IoTDB, how will the partition with this region be transferred?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

If there are 6 nodes in the cluster of Apache IoTDB Version 1.0, namely Node1, Node2, Node3, Node4, Node5, Node6, and the number of ConfigNodes I set is 3. If the partition with RegionID 1 is for Node1, Node2, and Node3, when I shut down Node1,Node2 and Node3, will the ConfigNodes of the partition with RegionID 1 be transferred to Node4, Node5, and Node6? In this case, can the cluster still insert data normally?

I checked all the information I can searched out, but still have no answer. Looking forward to getting response

Answer (score 0):

The ConfigNode of Apache IoTDB will not transfer, therefore if you close the nodes in RegionId=1, data managed by these nodes cannot be inserted. However, data in other partitions can be inserted if they are distributed in node4, 5, and 6.